# Using XML to calculate rates with PHP

Tags: php, xml, class

I'm a bit stuck and I hope someone who's more familiar with PHP will be able to help me. Basically I am writing a PHP application that lets you plug in products via an XML file. When I say products I mean like a car-hire or insurance type product, where there are forms to fill out and rates to calculate. I opted for an XML structure to make it easy in future to add new or adapt them without any coding knowledge as the underlying class will do all the work.
However I'm now trying to rack my brain for the safest and best way to include rates calculations in the XML file structure and evaluate them in PHP, without any risk of being exploited. 
So for example the xml file structure I will have for the rates calculation area might look something like

```
<rates>
  <rate name="variable1" type="forminput" relative="form['input1']"></rate>
  <rate name="variable2" type="forminput" relative="form['input2']"></rate>
  <rate name="calculatedvariable1" type="calculation">[variable1] * [variable2]</rate>
</rates>
```

Ok so this is a pretty basic example but the idea is that my class then reads the name, creates a php variable based on this using an xml parser, with the value given in the form (or wherever the relative is referencing) and then when it finds a calculation type it plugs the correctly named variables (noted by square brackets or whatever) into the calculation and evaluates it. 
So in this example the output given by parsing the calculation will be :

```
$variable1 * $variable2
```

Which then needs to run as a calculation to get the value of calculatedvariable1. Now I know I can use eval() to achieve this but I'm not convinced this is the only option and perhaps I'm missing something else I could be doing either in my xml structure or in the way my php will parse it. 
Anyhow I hope I've explained it properly and thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Sorry, I was just typing it up as a quick example of structure... no need to be a smart ass, I'm already sure you are much more intelligent than me ;-)

Comment: Yeah hence the smiley... I was kidding. But short comments and corrections are pretty much the definition of internet smart asses... lol

Comment: Insteead of `eval` I had the idea to use [`DOMXPath::evaluate`](http://php.net/DOMXPath.evaluate), you find an example below. It allows you to keep the syntax XML document specific, not PHP specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have solved the problem to retrieve the value from the form already in form of a string based on the `relative` attribute - naming the implementation here `resolve_variable($relative)`.

You can then assign the value to the element itself and formulate your calculation in form of a standard xpath 1.0 expression like:

```
rate[@name="variable1"] * rate[@name="variable2"]
```

And that expression inside the XML:

```
<rates>
  <rate name="variable1" type="forminput" relative="form['input1']"></rate>
  <rate name="variable2" type="forminput" relative="form['input2']"></rate>
  <rate name="calculatedvariable1" type="calculation">
    rate[@name="variable1"] * rate[@name="variable2"]
  </rate>
</rates>
```

All you need in PHP is to make use of the [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/DOMXPath) object for your [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

You can then assign the values to the nodes:

```
// assign values
foreach ($xpath->query('rate/@relative') as $relative) {
    $relative->ownerElement->nodeValue = resolve_variable($relative);
}
```

Then perform all the calculation(s):

```
// do calculations
$results = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('rate[@type="calculation"]') as $calculation) {
    $results[$calculation->getAttribute('name')]
        = $xpath->evaluate($calculation->nodeValue);
}
```

They then come out nicely in form of the `$results` array (in my example I have 3 and 5 as values):

```
Array
(
    [calculatedvariable1] => 15
)
```

Maybe this is helpful for you.

Take care that if you need precise calculations floating point arithmetics might stand in your way http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf

A working example at a glance for the whole picture / the view from above: http://eval.in/9595

You might be able to do this as well [with XSL](http://php.net/book.xsl).

Comment: Wow that is a much better system thank you, I don't normally work too much in XML so had no idea that it could be possible with something like this. And then as you say it's using xml standards which won't be such a risk when plugged back into the php. 
Floating point arithmetics shouldn't really enter into as it will only ever really be working with value that can be expressed as a currency amount so 2 decimal points as standard.
See, I told you, you were clearly much smarter than me.

Comment: Yes and because xpath is a deterministic language, you can dry-run this process, catch exceptions and therefore validate the XML/xpath input. That is useful, too. It would be much more complicated with some PHP code, and yes, `eval` is often asking for troubles. You can make it more save, but it does not work as easy as here with xpath.